# Build Activiti App from sources

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, activiti, business-process-management, alfresco-maven

I'm using Activiti 6.0 avaliable in 6.x Download ( https://www.activiti.org/get-started). I saw some bugs was fixed only in sources, so I thing that i shoud build   own release to deploy at my tomcat.
I’m trying to build (Make Activit-app.war, Activit-admin.war and and Activit-rest.war) using  sources: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/releases/tag/7.0.0.Beta1) and importing by  IntelliJ and Building (Crt +F9), but i’m not sure i’m doing by correct way.

Somone one can help  me with the steps for build Activiti Community (6.0 and 7.0 beta) from sources ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the maven clean install command with skipping testing, use the following command `mvn clean install -DskipTests`